# How to make this script work with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use a jQuery plugin (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/) for show the images in a div. It works fine. But. When I load new images into this div with ajax, it doesn't do anything.

I think the problem is here:

```
(function( window, $, undefined ) {
```

Here is my ajax call (sorry, I forgot it):

```
$('#albums').live('click', function() {
$('#left_col div').hide();
$.ajax({
    url: document.base_url + 'welcome/list_albums',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#thumbs, #images').html('');
        $('#glist').html(data).show();

        var $container  = $('#glist'),
            $imgs       = $container.find('img').hide(),
            totalImgs   = $imgs.length,
            cnt         = 0;


        $imgs.each(function(i) {
        var $img        = $(this);
        $('<img/>').load(function() {
            ++cnt;
            if( cnt === totalImgs ) {
                    $imgs.show();
                    $container.montage({
                            fillLastRow                             : true,
                            alternateHeight                 : true,
                            alternateHeightRange    : {
                                    min     : 70,
                                    max     : 140
                            }
                    });

                    /*
                     * just for this demo:
                     */
                    $('#overlay').fadeIn(500);
            }
        }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
        });     
    }
});
return false;
```

});

So, my question is: how can I reload this script or make it somehow work with ajax.

Comment: Show us your server's response...

Comment: We need to see your code; the code that initializes your plugin and the code that does the AJAX request.

Comment: @TOUDIdel. It's nothing with the server. The plugin probably not using delegate event attach. `on`\ `delegate`\ `live`

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question with the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

There is "Example 4" on the plugin example page that shows exactly what you want. There is a "Load More" button that will execute the following code

```
$('#loadmore').show().bind('click', function() {
    var len = imgarr.length;
    for( var i = 0, newimgs = ''; i < 15; ++i ) {
        var pos = Math.floor( Math.random() * len ),
        src = imgarr[pos];
        newimgs += '<a href=""><img src="images/' + src + '.jpg"/></a>';
    }
    var $newimages = $( newimgs );
    $newimages.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.append( $newimages ).montage( 'add', $newimages );
    });
});
```

So essentially it creates a string with the new (anchored) images, wraps this string into a jQuery object and implements a callback for when the images inside the string have been loaded. After they have been loaded, you'll have to call .montage() with the 'add' parameter and the jQuery object as a second parameter.

Comment: Yeap, I've seen this, but it's not what I need. I want to fill the div with new images, then use this plugin. Thx for your answer.

Comment: Ahem, but the code line inside the imagesLoaded() callback is exactly doing this ... filling the $container with the new images and then use the plugin. I don't think there is any other (easy) way